# MySQL select new columns for adjacency matrix

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

I want to construct an [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) from some data. Suppose the vertices of the graph are user names. How do I select a set of user names from my data to be columns? The rows should just be a `select user_name from table`

1. How can I select user_names from my data to be columns?

Comment: Can you provide a small example of the kind of resultset you hope to see?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT`. There are plenty of posts here on how to apply it.

Comment: I want each user_name to be it's own column as well. Could you direct me somewhere for this ability?

Comment: Here is a link for you [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns/12005676#12005676)